# Serde untagged attribute on enum results in stack overflow

Tags: rust, serde

Im using the `untagged` attribute on an enum to serialize and deserialize JSON.

```rust
// Just an example of using `untagged` - not actual code with the issue.
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Message {
    String(String),
    X(X),
}
```

I get a `fatal runtime error: stack overflow` for some of my types at runtime.

These types may have recursive definitions by using `Box`.

In general what would cause a stack overflow when using an `untagged` attribute?

The docs do not state any limitations so it seems like it should work for any code that compiles.

This is a stack trace I collected with Instruments/Sampler on Mac OS, `__rust_probestack` seems to be the last function called, at that point it's around 70 functions deep.

[image: stack]

Comment: Could you update the code to include `Params`, `Value`, and an example which reproduces the issue (optionally link to [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/))

Comment: This is just an example of where the `untagged` attribute would be used, the example does not trigger the `stack overflow`. Im not exactly sure what does hence the question. My code base has quite a lot of structs and Im not sure how to reproduce it with minimal code.

Comment: This sounds like it's time to work on actually creating a minimal reproduction. What you do is delete parts of your program (unnecessary struct fields, etc) except for ones that make the problem go away, and keep going until you have a small program (though not one that makes sense with respect to your original goal). At the end, it's quite possible that the problem will be obvious to you! And if it's something that could be considered a bug in Serde, then you now have material for a bug report.

Comment: A stack overflow just means you put more data on the stack than there is space. On Unix-like operating systems you can see the stack size in kilobytes with `ulimit -s`. You can also increase it for you job and see whether that fixes it. The most common way of dealing with this is to put the data on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: Do you have any indication that the `untagged` flag is related to the stack overflow?

Comment: @SvenMarnach The SO happens after a call to serde to parse JSON into enums/structs. The call does not return. My code compiles so all types are valid. Using vanilla serde, nothing custom.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `ulimit -s` returns 8192, and the JSON is string is much smaller than 1MB, so surely this would not be an issue? Also String, Vec and Box are used quite often in the tree of data too.

Comment: It would definitely help to see your actual struct definition, and the definitions of the types involved. Your question makes it seem like the actual example you posted causes a stack overflow, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: The most common cause of stack overflows is infinite recursion. You don't have anything like `enum Foo { Bar { foo: Box<Foo>, … }, …` among your "_quite a log of structs_" do you?

Comment: @Jmb Yes I have recursive types but the input JSON is only a few levels deep, and I have tested what my code is doing in general and it seems to pass: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53a3a6564a2991106e37b8a8a9215680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1062#issuecomment-335659227

Fixed by setting the stack to 16MB:

`export RUST_MIN_STACK=16777216 && cargo test`

Answer (score 4):

According to what you said in the comments, you have recursive types. The problem comes from the way `untagged` works. Here's a minimal example that reproduces the problem:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Foo {
    Foo(Box<Foo>),
    Bar(String),
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#""Bar""#;

    let _v: Foo = serde_json::from_str(&data).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04a58971b18b767f5e1cde28e8dc3917)

The problem is that with `untagged`, Serde tries to parse the data as the first variant of the enum, then if that fails it backtracks and tries the second variant and so on. Here's what happens with the example above:

1. Serde is asked to parse a value of type `Foo`, which is untagged, so Serde tries to parse a value matching the first variant.
2. The first variant is a `Box<Foo>`, so Serde tries to parse a value of type `Foo`, which is untagged, so Serde tries to parse a value matching the first variant.
3. The first variant is a `Box<Foo>`, so Serde tries to parse a value of type `Foo`, which is untagged, so Serde tries to parse a value matching the first variant.
4. And so on.

Note that this has nothing to do with the input data, this code fails before even attempting to read a single byte of data!

To avoid the issue, you must make sure that Serde will always consume some data before recursing, eg.:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Foo {
    Foo(String, Box<Foo>),
    Bar(String),
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#""Bar""#;

    let _v: Foo = serde_json::from_str(&data).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1f3b244b05bd01dbdbf41c1868394f3)

Comment: Thanks. In my code scalar values like String come first, and enums only contain exact structs - so these should stop the recursion? The structs may contain the enum and recurse back again, but wouldn't `untagged` match the input JSON level by level (and not recurse into deeper levels without making sure the JSON can match at each level)?

Comment: As an example, why doesn't this result in a stack overflow? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e0e678e87e99d325e032b0f0cd73bae

Comment: There's nothing in the JSON that identifies a struct. A struct "matches" if it could be parsed, so if the first field in your struct is the untagged enum, Serde will recurse immediately.

Comment: You example doesn't overflow because the first field of each struct is a tag, so the recursion stops as soon as there is no tag at the current level (which is also the way Serde's standard enums work).

Comment: But tags at the end of structs + JSON still works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f54825192d79fc2cb1d0b1a1d55de6dd